# Unable to manipulate 2d Plot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I'm given the instruction:

> Create a dynamic 2-D plot of:
>
> e^(-a x)  where  0<=x<=1  With a continuous slider for  a  where 
>   0<=a<=10

So I enter:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[e^(-ax), {x,0,1}],
  {a,0,10}
]
```

but the result is an empty graph. However,

```
Plot[e^(-x), {x,0,1}]
```

works just fine. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I believe I'm using the manipulate function according to the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this but your expression `e^(-ax)` looks to me as if it ought to be `e^(-a*x)` -- `ax` is a two-letter name, you need either a multiplication sign or a space to tell Mathematica that you mean `-a*x`.

Close inspection of your instruction shows a space between `-a` and `x`.